# Populate jQuery UI accordion after AngularJS service call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs

I'm currently trying to build an AngularJS app where I'm using a jQuery UI accordion control.

The problem is, that the jQuery UI accordion is initiated *before* my AngularJS service is done loading data from the server. In other words: the accordion doesn't have any data when it's initiated and thus does not show when the data from AngularJS is populated.

The view looks like this:

```
<!-- Pretty standard accordion markup omitted -->
$("#b2b-line-accordion").togglepanels();
```

My AngularJS controller looks like this:

```
app.controller('orderController', function ($scope, orderService, userService) {
// Constructor for this controller
init();

function init() {
    $scope.selected = {};
    $scope.totalSum = 0.00;
    $scope.shippingDate = "";
    $scope.selectedShippingAddress = "";
    $scope.orderComment = "";
    $scope.agreements = false;
    $scope.passwordResetSuccess = false;
    $scope.passwordResetError = true;

    userService.getCurrentUser(2).then(function (response) {
        $scope.user = response.data;

        orderService.getProductCategoriesWithProducts($scope.user).then(function (d) {
            $scope.categories = d.data;
        });
    });
}

// Other methods omitted
});
```

And my AngularJS services looks like this:

```
app.service('orderService', function ($http) {
    this.getProductCategoriesWithProducts = function (user) {
        return $http.post('url to my service', user);
    };
});

app.service('userService', function ($http) {
    this.getCurrentUser = function(companyId) {
        return $http.get('url to my service' + companyId + '.aspx');
    };

    this.resetPassword = function() {
        return true;
    };
});
```

Is there any way to tell the accordion to "wait" to initialise until the data is returned from the service? :-)

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

I tried chaining the methods and added some logging and it seems that the accordion is in fact initiated after the JSON is returned from the service.

```
    userService.getCurrentUser(2).then(function(response) {
        $scope.user = response.data;
    }).then(function() {
        orderService.getProductCategoriesWithProducts($scope.user).then(function(d) {
            $scope.categories = d.data;
            console.log("categories loaded");
        }).then(function () {
            $("#b2b-line-accordion").accordion();
            console.log("accordion loaded");
        });
    });
```

However, it doesn't display the accordion :-( The first accordion div looks fine in the generated DOM:

```
<div id="b2b-line-accordion" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" role="tablist"> 
    ... 
</div>
```

But the rest of the markup (which is databound with angular) itsn't initiated.

Complete markup:

```
<div id="b2b-line-accordion">
    <div ng-repeat="productCategory in categories">
        <h3>{{ productCategory.CategoryName }}</h3>
        <div class="b2b-line-wrapper">
            <table>
                <tr>
                      <th>Betegnelse</th>
                      <th>Str.</th>
                      <th>Enhed</th>
                      <th>HF varenr.</th>
                      <th>Antal</th>
                      <th>Bemærkninger</th>
                      <th>Beløb</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="product in productCategory.Products">
                    <td>{{ product.ItemGroupName }}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.ItemAttribute }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <select ng-model="product.SelectedVariant"
                                ng-options="variant as variant.VariantUnit for variant in product.Variants"
                                ng-init="product.SelectedVariant = product.Variants[0]"
                                ng-change="calculateLinePrice(product); calculateTotalPrice();">
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ product.ItemNumber }}</td>
                    <td class="line-amount">
                        <span class="ensure-number-label" ng-show="product.IsNumOfSelectedItemsValid">Indtast venligst et tal</span>
                        <input type="number" class="line-amount" name="amount" min="0" ng-change="ensureNumber(product); calculateLinePrice(product); calculateTotalPrice();" ng-model="product.NumOfSelectedItems" value="{{ product.NumOfSelectedItems }}" />
                    <td>
                       <input type="text" name="line-comments" ng-model="product.UserComment" value="{{ product.UserComment }}" /></td>
                    <td><span class="line-sum">{{ product.LinePrice | currency:"" }}</span></td>
                 </tr>
           </table>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**SOLUTION**

Finally I found a way around this! I'm not entirely sure if it's that pretty and if it's the Angular-way of doing stuff (I guess it isn't)

Made a directive with the following code:

```
app.directive('accordion', function () {
    return {
         restrict: 'A',
         link: function ($scope, $element, attrs) {
             $(document).ready(function () {
                $scope.$watch('categories', function () {
                    if ($scope.categories != null) {
                         $element.accordion();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

So basically when the DOM is ready and when the categories array changes (which it does when the data has been loaded), I'm initiating the jQuery UI accordion.

Thanks a lot t @Sgoldy for pointing me in the right direction here!

Comment: Have you checkout out Angular's [jQuery UI adapter](https://github.com/angular/angular-jquery-ui)? I used one made by another group for [jQuery Mobile](https://github.com/opitzconsulting/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter) that provided an angular directive and it worked well. I see that you've found a solution but this may follow angular convention a bit better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you need a `directive` and you can handle this more angular way !

In `HTML` define the directive

```
<div ui-accordion="accordionData" ></div>
```

Return `promise` from your `service` and pass the `promise` to the directive.

In controller

```
$scope.accordionData = myService.getAccordionData();
```

The `ui-accordion` directive looks like

```
.directive('uiAccordion', function($timeout) {
return {
  scope:{
    myAccordionData: '=uiAccordion'
  },
  template: '<div ng-repeat="item in myData"><h3 ng-bind="item.title"></h3><div><p ng-bind="item.data"></p></div></div>',
  link: function(scope, element) {
    scope.myAccordionData.then(function(data) {
      scope.myData = data;
      generateAccordion();
    });

    var generateAccordion = function() {
      $timeout(function() {   //<--- used $timeout to make sure ng-repeat is REALLY finished
        $(element).accordion({
          header: "> div > h3"
        });
       });
     }
   }
  }
})
```

When your service call succeed `then` you create your accordion. Here you can define your own `accordion-template` like

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myData">
  <h3 ng-bind="item.title"></h3>
  <div>
     <p ng-bind="item.data"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Template binds with your model data `myData`. I use `ng-repeat` inside the template to create `accordion-header` and `accordion-body` `HTML`.

In the `generateAccordion` method i use `$timeout` to make sure the `ng-repeat` is really finished rendering because `$timeout` will execute at the end of the current digest cycle.

Check the <kbd>[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/PPXyIfNnDFCXwfKLRySp?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Reza, thanks a lot for your example, it's greatly appreciated and makes sense! :-) I like that solution aswell. The only thing I've always found a bit "shaky" (for the lack of a better word) is using timeout to wait for async calls to finish. What if the server is slow for some reason and it takes longer than the timeout? :-)

Other than that, I think it's a brilliant example!

Comment: @bomortensen may be you miss-understood, i use `$timeout` in my service to simulate **fake $http** call. This code block `$timeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve(data);
      }, 1000);` will be replaced with your real implementation. And check my updated answer why i use `$timeout` inside my directive

Answer (score 1):

My best practice is to resolve your asynchronous services before controller is initiated.

As you can see in the document, http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeProvider

> resolve - {Object.=} - An optional map of
>   dependencies which should be injected into the controller. If any of
>   these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to
>   be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is
>   instantiated. If all the promises are resolved successfully, the
>   values of the resolved promises are injected and $routeChangeSuccess
>   event is fired. If any of the promises are rejected the
>   $routeChangeError event is fired.

Your controller and view won't be even started before your service is resolved or rejected.

There is a good video tutorial about this, https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-resolve

In your case, you can config routes like the following

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'main.html',
    controller: orderController,
    resolve: {
      categories: function(orderService) {
        return orderService.getProductCategoriesWithProducts();
      },
      user: function(userService) {
        return userService.getCurrentUser();
      }
    }
  });
```

Then, with your controller

```
app.controller('orderController', function($scope, categories, user) {
   //categories and user is always here, so use it.
});
```

I have also found a similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654195/http-request-before-angularjs-app-initialises)

Comment: Hi allenhwkim, thanks a lot for your answer! I learned a lot from it :-) Wasn't aware of the resolve method, it sure seems like the best way to ensure data is loaded before the controller is put to use. The only hurdle I have now is, that my views are dynamic and comes from Umbraco CMS, so setting the templateUrl is another "issue" that I need to take care of now ;-)

Comment: For 3rd party template url, you can set your own server to provide url which allow CORS(haven't tried this way) or [dynamic url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423054/dynamically-loading-the-controller-in-angularjs-routeprovider).