# How to populate data in JQueryUI accordion using Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

In the following code sample, **accordion** directive ensures that angular finishes first and then allow the JQueryUI to render the accordion with provided values in tags. But it's not working as expected. I'm following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190594/populate-jquery-ui-accordion-after-angularjs-service-call).

```
<div accordion>
  <h3 ng-repeat-start="user in users" >
    <a href="#">{{user.name}}</a>
  </h3>
  <div ng-repeat-end>
      Name: {{user.name}}<br>
      Type: {{user.type}}<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

The following is the accordion directive implementation`

```
app.directive('accordion', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
      link: function ($scope, $element, attrs) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $scope.$watch('users', function () {
            if ($scope.users != null) {
              $timeout(function(){
                $element.accordion();
              });
            }
          });
        });
      }
  };
});
```

JS Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/7028yLdh/1/

Comment: How so "This is the wrong place.."? Looking at your first html example, your `ng-repeat-end` looks good to me

Comment: because it's not setting name & type in div.

Comment: It should, can you provide a jsfiddle for reproduction?

Comment: @devqon, you're correct. It's problem with the directive, I guess. Please fix so that I can have the data in accordion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.$watch('users', /* ... */)` won't get called unless the Array changes to a different object. So your `elem.accordion()` is not running after the DOM is compiled. Instead you can watch `users.length` to detect new elements in the Array.

Also, `$(document).ready` is not needed inside Angular directive link functions.

One more pitfall is that you must call `elem.accordion('destroy')` and re-build the accordion on subsequent changes to the array. My solution will only build the accordion once by default, unless you supply a `watch="someVariable"` to watch for changes.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hk6wro4y/

HTML:

```
<!-- Will not update -->
<div accordion><!-- content --></div>

<!-- Will update -->
<div accordion watch="users.length"><!-- content --></div>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('accordion', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {          
          if (attrs.watch) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.watch, function () {
              if (elem.hasClass('ui-accordion')) { 
                elem.accordion('destroy'); 
              }
              elem.accordion();
            });
          }
          else {
            $timeout(function () {
              elem.accordion();
            });
          }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks William B. Can you plz fix the js fiddle you provided. On clicking new user, it's not added to Accordion. I'll need that.

Comment: @AdarshSinghal I mentioned in my comment that by default it will not update. You need to supply the `watch="users"` if you want it to explicitly watch and update on change of the list

Comment: @WilliamB Thankyou very much... you made my day.

Comment: I have made a small change to remove the need for an isolate scope to be more flexible & semantic.